# Visual studio 2010 win 32 project import DLL

Tags: c, visual-studio-2010, dll

I started a new Win 32 console application project in VS2010..
It is known that you cant add reference to dll from references tabs, as Projects tab appears only...

Under linker project properties i can see that i am able to specify only .lib files not dll.

I have the header file and dll and lib but i want to use dll. Is it imposible to use dll with this type of project??

Comment: You have the .lib. The IDE wants you to use the .lib. Use the .lib.

Comment: If you are usually on Limux you might be use to link against the dynamic library, because everything is the same file. On Windows it is just two separate files, a .lib for the linker and a .DLL when you run the program.

Comment: thank for the info.. I am planning to use it both at linux/win environment:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The linker doesn't know how to use a native DLL.  The import library for the DLL is required.

Comment: you mean that it is impossible ??

Comment: doesn't know == impossible.  Why does this matter if you have the .lib?

Comment: just curiocity.. as i see although having lib you also need dll